# Cómo devolver imágenes en base a parámetros ingresados

Tags: php

Lo que quiero es que mediante entrar a una dirección: **www.mipagina.com/imagen.php/parametro1/parametro2/parametro3**, la misma me devuelva una imágen.
¿Que son cada parámetro?

1. Parametro1: usuario.
2. Parametro2: clave
3. Parametro3: id de la imagen.

El código con el que logro visualizar la imagen que necesito (en este caso un ejemplo) es:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/x-png'); //or whatever
readfile('23456.png');
die();
?>
```

Y el código que ya tengo para leer los parametros, consultar una base MySQL y seguir (si hay resultados) es:

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "db_local";
    $password = "123456";
    $dbname = "prueba";

    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    $request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'));
    $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

    $usuario = array_shift($request);
    $clave = array_shift($request);

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
          echo "La conexion no ha sido posible";
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT V.* FROM `VAR_GLOBAL` V INNER JOIN CLIENTES C ON C.NCliente LIKE '$usuario' AND C.Nombre LIKE '$clave';";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

          echo $row['EncPwd'] . "|" . $row['EncPwd2'];
        }
    } else {
        echo "No hay resultados";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Mi idea es que si la consulta resulta satisfactoria el script devuelva al usuario la imagen pero no en formato HTML () sino que como un archivo tal como lo hace el primer código que coloqué.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de unas horas de investigación llegué a la conclusión de que los códigos que estaba usando no eran compatibles. Encontré entonces otro código para mostrar una imágen:

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("prueba.png");

header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Lo uní, y funcionó perfectamente:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "db_local";
    $password = "123456";
    $dbname = "prueba";

    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    $request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'));
    $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

    $usuario = array_shift($request);
    $clave = array_shift($request);
    $imagen = array_shift($request);


    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
          echo "La conexion no ha sido posible";
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT V.* FROM `VAR_GLOBAL` V INNER JOIN CLIENTES C ON C.NCliente LIKE '$usuario' AND C.Nombre LIKE '$clave';";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {        
   $im = imagecreatefrompng("$imagen.png");
   header('Content-Type: image/png');
   imagepng($im);
   imagedestroy($im);
         }
    } else {
        echo "No hay resultados";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

**Accedo a el como: www.mipagina.com/imagen.php/usuario/clave/idimagen**.